# How to get automatic slides rotation of images in mobile app for updated ionic 3?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, slideshow, ionic3

How to get automatic slides rotation of images in mobile app for updated ionic 3 ?
Previously I was getting image slide rotation but after ionic 3 I'm not getting.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

To get automatic play in slides, just us the property `autoplay` on `ion-slides` element.

Example:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides autoplay=3000 speed=1000 loop=true effect=slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <!-- Slide 1 -->
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <!-- Slide 2 -->
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <!-- Slide 3 -->
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I'm using autoplay but after using this, app is not opening home page. Its stuck on splash screen. code is written below :- <ion-slides autoplay=1500> <ion-slide *ngFor = "let banners of bannersImage"> <img src={{banners.image}}> </ion-slide> </ion-slides>

Comment: You are saying that you are stuck in the Splash screen? Do you call splashScreen.hide(); when your platform is ready?

Comment: Yes I'm using splashScreen.hide in my config.xml. If I'm using autoplay = XXXX then only its not going to home screen. Only automatic slide is not working, I can slide manually my images.